# how to set the X:Name property through C# in wpf datagrid column

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

In WPF Datagrid, i am adding Column dynamically for that i want to set X:Name property of DataGrid column by C#

My Code:

```
DataGridTextColumn clm = new DataGridTextColumn();
                    clm.Header = "Marks";
                    clm.Width = 100;
                    clm.IsReadOnly = false;
                    dgChapters.Columns.Add(clm);
```

How to set X:Name property on DataGridTextColumn by C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//Registe it in a Method of a Window class
this.RegisterName("mark", clm);
//Use it in another Method like this
DataGridTextColumn clm2 = this.FindName("mark") as DataGridTextColumn;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, How to retrieve that column name value in C#

Comment: NameScope namescope = NameScope.GetNameScope(this) as NameScope;
    if(namescope!=null)
    {
        //namescope.Keys contains all name you've registed before
    }

Comment: namescope is always null, its not storing created RegisterName

Comment: The type of namescope may change in different context, so, you should peek it with a breakpoint before...

Comment: var namescope = NameScope.GetNameScope(this);//add a breakpoint after this, and see what the type of namescope is, then change it..

Comment: In .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5, the type of namescope is NameScope

Comment: by var namescope, i am getting all regiternames, but i am not getting namescope.keys